# How to get Mac OSX Finder to preview programming text files that don't have .txt or .text extension?

Tags: macos

Programming obviously involves lots of text file usage. You often want to see what you did somewhere else in some other program, without loading up that whole program into your current IDE of choice.

If I copy a text file from say `fred.cpp` to `fred.cpp.text`, I can view the contents of the file from the Finder's preview. But I don't want to have copy or rename all my development files.

In a 2003 (!) post on MacOSHints, there is an instruction to do this

`find . -name *.xml -exec SetFile -t TEXT {} ;`

(in that case, for *.xml files), but this didn't work for me due to issues with the `exec` command. But in any case, surely there's a better way to do it from the GUI?

Either way though: a command-line or a GUI solution would be great, thanks!

Comment: On your system, what application is currently associated with .cpp files?  You need an application on your system that associates the `cpp` file extension with the `public.c-plus-plus-source` UTI.  Xcode is one such application.  Finder and QuickLook will recognize `public.c-plus-plus-source` files as text, among many others.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Uniform Type Identifiers that Apple maintains in OSX. In my case I also have .cs (C Sharp) files that are text only, and I don't think are catered for by Apple's UTI, although there may be a workaround of some sort. The QLStephen QuickLook add-on suggested by the accepted answer below from @2called-chaos seems to be the most generic way to add a whole raft of source code files to be Quick-Look-able.

Comment: Just viewing this question of mine again, and I see that there is some confusion between the QuickLook at a file, and the file Preview. A Quicklook is when you select the file and hit the spacebar... then if the appropriate QL plugin exists for that filetype, the Finder will display a window showing the contents of the file. But this isn't the `Preview` of the given file type. And the below answers about QuickLook, and possible plugins, don't seem to address that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the [Textmate QuickLook](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/15/quicklook-and-textmate) plugin which only works with Textmate running.

**Pro:** Syntax Highlighting
**Contra:** Only with (non-free) Textmate running

---

Alternatively: [QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/)

> QLStephen is an Apple OSX QuickLook plugin that lets you view plain text files without a file extension.

But it works for all plain text files (even with extension).

**Pro:** Stable and free
**Contra:** No syntax highlighting

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the pointer to the QLStephen plugin. Worked like a charm, making sure to run the `qlmanage -r` at the end of copying the program to the /Library/Quicklook folder. I don't yet know what filetypes it might be limited to, but it works for me just fine without change with *.c, *.cpp, and *.c# files.

Comment: Possibilities are endless, cause you can preview virtually any text file using: [Adding Language Types](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode#adding-language-types)

Answer (score 22):

Update: I didn't manage to get `qlcolorcode` to work properly on the latest MacOS (10.15+) so I switched to this one.

https://github.com/sbarex/SourceCodeSyntaxHighlight

which can be installed with

```
brew install --cask --no-quarantine syntax-highlight
```

Original answer below

---

2 years late but you can use

https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode

install via brew [cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask)

```
brew cask install qlcolorcode
```

or

```
brew install --cask qlcolorcode
```

(if you have a newer brew.)

for more nice usages of the quicklook, check this repo

https://github.com/sindresorhus/quick-look-plugins

Comment: Still works in June 2022. Didn't even need to restart the Mac.